# Statistics of pronunciation of "poor"

Tags: pronunciation

I discovered recently that in England (where I live for the last 12 years) the more standard way to pronouns "poor" is pɔː rather than pʊə. It was a real shock to me since I was certain that one should say pʊə. So I would like to know how common is pɔː/pʊə pronunciation in UK, are there regional differences? Also, are there English speaking countries where one is supposed to say pʊə?

Oxford dictionary says that both are Ok  and puts pɔː the first https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/poor

Comment: I was just in an Irish pub in the United States and the waitress -- who was from Liverpool -- pronounced "pub" in a distinctly different way from how an RP speaker would say it.  So I think you'll get a different answer in London than you will in Liverpool, Belfast, or Glasgow -- much less New York City, Sydney, or Cape Town.

Comment: Lambie, I've started this investigation but surprisingly my English students don't always acknowledge existence of  pɔː/pʊə pronunciation. Moreover they propose some other ways to pronouns "poor" which I can't spell phonetically. Moreover, they give contradictory information about locations in UK where one is supposed to say  pɔː/pʊə

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is irrelevant for learning English, it is about pronunciation and is largely opinion-based.

Comment: Laugh, I don't see how this is irrelevant for learning English. I was speaking to my PhD student from Manchester and told him "Poor you" and I was using pʊə pronunciation. He was not able to understand what I say... Don't you think, this is relevant for learning English?...

Comment: Great question +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

John Wells' *Longman Pronunciation Dictionary* includes "preference polls" for the pronunciation of several words.  As it happens, it includes a poll for *poor* in British English:

[image: Preference poll for 'poor']

According to the LPD, /pɔː/ is favoured by 74% of BrE speakers, while /pʊə/ is favoured by only 26% of speakers.  Among BrE speakers born before 1942, /pʊə/ is favoured by 41%, so we can see there's been a shift toward /pɔː/ over time.

In American English, /pʊr/ is the usual pronunciation, although /pɔːr/ and /poʊr/ are also used.